# Contact form with dropdown of contacts

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I am working on a site design for my son's school/church. They have 3 primary departments: Church, School and Daycare. They want users to be able to email each department using a dropdown menu in the contact form. I thought I had it working, but after testing it seems it is only emailing to the default email I have setup to email if nobody selects a department from the menu. So, the email form is being processed and sent, but it is only emailing to the default. Any ideas how I can get this to work? I am a web designer/graphic designer and do not have much experience with PHP.

Below is my code:
HTML:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Who do you wish to contact?</label>
            <select class="form-control empty" id="selectDept" name="deptid" required data-validation-required-message="Please make a selection.">
                <option>SELECT...</option>
                <option value="church">Faith Lutheran Church</option>
                <option value="school">K-5 School</option>
                <option value="preschool">Touching Hearts Preschool</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br> 

    <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" id="captcha_code" maxlength="6" />
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false"><span class="captchaImage"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></span></a>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$response = array('error' => true, 'message' => 'OK');

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
empty($_POST['email'])      ||
empty($_POST['phone'])      ||
empty($_POST['message'])    ||
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $response['message'] = "No arguments Provided!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
    $response['message'] = "The security code entered was incorrect.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
//$to = 'info@faithlutheran.org'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
switch ($_POST['deptid']) {
    case "church":
        $to = "church@domain.com";
        break;
    case "school":
        $to = "school@domain.com";
        break;
    case "preschool":
        $to = "preschool@domain.com";
        break;
    default:
        $to = "info@domain.com";
        break;
}
$email_subject = "General Question from Website:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from Faith Lutheran website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@domain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

$response['error'] = false;

die(json_encode($response));

?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            // Prevent spam click and default submit behaviour
            $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
            event.preventDefault();

            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var captcha_code = $("input#captcha_code").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    captcha_code: captcha_code,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.error) {

                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>The security code enstered was incorrect.");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    } else {
                    // Enable button & show success message
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                        }
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

// When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: You don't have a `deptid` field in your ajax post

Answer (score 0):

If it only send to the default email address, I think the cause is here:

```
switch ($_POST['deptid']) {
case "church":
    $to = "church@domain.com";
    break;
case "school":
    $to = "school@domain.com";
    break;
case "preschool":
    $to = "preschool@domain.com";
    break;
default:
    $to = "info@domain.com";
    break;
}
```

Try to var_dump the $_POST['deptid'] variable, and check if it contains that you want.